freeze some layers in ResNet
I am new to PyTorch and ML programming. I want to train a ResNet for image classification and I am attempting to freeze all layers of the ResNet except for layer4 and FC layers. The following is my code:
model = resnet18(pretrained=True)
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if 'layer4' not in name and 'fc' not in name:
        param.requires_grad = False

However, when I print the layers that will be used in the network subsequently:
parameter_to_train = net.parameters()
print("Parameters that will be trained:")
parameter_to_train = []
for name,param in net.named_parameters():
    if param.requires_grad == True:
        parameter_to_train.append(param)
        print("\t",name)

the layers are not getting frozen.
Output of the above code:
Parameters that will be trained:
 conv1.weight
 bn1.weight
 bn1.bias
 layer1.0.conv1.weight
 layer1.0.bn1.weight
 layer1.0.bn1.bias
 layer1.0.conv2.weight
 layer1.0.bn2.weight
 layer1.0.bn2.bias
 layer1.1.conv1.weight
 layer1.1.bn1.weight
 layer1.1.bn1.bias
 layer1.1.conv2.weight
 layer1.1.bn2.weight
 layer1.1.bn2.bias
 layer2.0.conv1.weight
 layer2.0.bn1.weight
 layer2.0.bn1.bias
 layer2.0.conv2.weight
 layer2.0.bn2.weight
 layer2.0.bn2.bias
 layer2.0.downsample.0.weight
 layer2.0.downsample.1.weight
 layer2.0.downsample.1.bias
 layer2.1.conv1.weight
 layer2.1.bn1.weight
 layer2.1.bn1.bias
 layer2.1.conv2.weight
 layer2.1.bn2.weight
 layer2.1.bn2.bias
 layer3.0.conv1.weight
 layer3.0.bn1.weight
 layer3.0.bn1.bias
 layer3.0.conv2.weight
 layer3.0.bn2.weight
 layer3.0.bn2.bias
 layer3.0.downsample.0.weight
 layer3.0.downsample.1.weight
 layer3.0.downsample.1.bias
 layer3.1.conv1.weight
 layer3.1.bn1.weight
 layer3.1.bn1.bias
 layer3.1.conv2.weight
 layer3.1.bn2.weight
 layer3.1.bn2.bias
 layer4.0.conv1.weight
 layer4.0.bn1.weight
 layer4.0.bn1.bias
 layer4.0.conv2.weight
 layer4.0.bn2.weight
 layer4.0.bn2.bias
 layer4.0.downsample.0.weight
 layer4.0.downsample.1.weight
 layer4.0.downsample.1.bias
 layer4.1.conv1.weight
 layer4.1.bn1.weight
 layer4.1.bn1.bias
 layer4.1.conv2.weight
 layer4.1.bn2.weight
 layer4.1.bn2.bias
 fc.weight
 fc.bias

Where I am going wrong? I am new to this and learning. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

What is the difference between model and net? The code you posted correctly sets requires_grad to False when I run it

That was indeed the problem and i missed to see it. Thanks for helping me out.

Now that the question is solved, I am voting to close.
